# How to send email via Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to send an image taken from Glass with below code...

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent( android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {     
    "xyz@gmail.com" });
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My image attached");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imageLocation));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

But I am getting "No apps can perform this action". I believe that there is no such intent in Glass. Can anyone provide the alternate solution, so that I can send email through Glass.

Comment: http://sendgrid.com/blog/google-glass-tutorial-sends-email-visually/ take a look at this..

Answer (score 0):

Without an email intent on Glass you will have to do it in a more raw way, there are instructions in this answer for doing so, including emails with an attached image, note the part about internet permission:

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I don't want to mention user's id and password unlike doing with intent :(