# google glass send or share binary data using GDK

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I develop a glassware that can produce binary data. The data format may be Audio or Video and it will be stored on SdCard. After these data has been created, I want to share it easily with other people or send email with an attachment to them.

So, I use the standard Android API (`Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE|Intent.ACTION_SEND`)to send email, but an error occured :

[image]

Is there any way to  share binary data with others on Google glass through GDK?

Mirror API can do this?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, GDK does not support action send and share yet.

A feature request has been submitted [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=230) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=364).

See [How to send email via Glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358617/how-to-send-email-via-glass)

You have to use JavaMail API.

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Comment: Thanks!EntryLevelDev. It seem that JavaMail API is what I don't really want. It should special the accurate email address to send. But I expect the user to choose the address to be send.